# Pyinstaller and SQLalchemy probelems

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyinstaller, exe

after i Make an exe of a .py file i get this erroe when trying to run it. sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8). anyone have any ideas?

iv tried everything i know how

Comment: Presumably the `.exe` contains a hardcoded path to the SQLite database file, and you are trying to run it in an environment where that path is not valid?

Comment: @snakechamberb ill let into that and let you know the outcome, thank you

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.